# How to stream data from Kafka to Spark when both are on different Docker containers?

Tags: docker, pyspark, apache-kafka, anaconda

I am trying to create a pipeline between Kafka and Spark. Because I have Windows I was obliged to use Docker in order to achieve my goal. The setup is the following: There is a Kafka container created using the image confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.2.0 and in another container with Anaconda with pyspark version 3.3.0.
I had tried different configurations for my pipeline, and this one with the two containers seems to be most promising.
My problem is that pyspark do not know where the Kafka data is, I get always the error: "Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".
I already tested Kafka with a toy example producer/consumer (in Anaconda) and works as expected, so I am 99 % sure the error is coming from pyspark. This is my code:

```
KAFKA_TOPIC = "songTopic"
KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP = 'kafka:9092' 

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Spotify Streaming Reccomendation System") \
        .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

songs_df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP) \
        .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC) \
        .load()
```

I think it complains exactly in the part format("kafka"). In advance I thank you for all the ideas and any help you can give me.

Comment: Are you providing appropriate package/s while starting your spark app as mentioned here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying

Comment: Thanks for answering, I included the environmental variable as: "os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0 pyspark-shell". Still I get the same error

Comment: Please note that the package that you are providing should be available in the docker container so that it can be used by spark. And I am not sure about this os level setting, I do not see it in the doc nor have I tried it. Any reason you did not do it the same way as explained in the doc?